# Xamarin, how to detect installation origin in Android

Tags: android, xamarin, installation, apk, bundle

I need to detect if the origin of installation of my app is from downloaded apk or from store. Some devices haven't the Play Store installed and I need to send different api request based on it.

Which is the best way?

1. A build with a preprocessor directive to distinguish apk / aab? But I don't found anything.
2. Checks if the Play Store is installed by searching the Package name from list of installed?
3. A c# code to check if the origin of installation is from Store or Apk?

I've tried the 2 solution by searching in the installed packages the package "com.android.vending", but in the emulator the Play Store isn't installed and, despite it all, the package appears in the list!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the case about [Is there a way to get the installer source of android app in the native android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70421457/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-installer-source-of-android-app).
You can put the following code in the MainActivity's OnCreate method:

```
string installpackage;
PackageManager package = this.PackageManager;
if(Build.VERSION.SdkInt > BuildVersionCodes.R)
{
      installpackage = package.GetInstallSourceInfo(this.PackageName).InitiatingPackageName;
}
else
{
      installpackage = package.GetInstallerPackageName(this.PackageName);
}
if (installpackage == "com.android.vending") // install from the google play
```

Answer (score 0):

If the Play Store is not installed on the device, we can check for the presence of the Google Play services package, which is installed on most Android devices. We can use the PackageInfo class to get information about the Google Play services package and check if it's installed. [0]

```
try 
{ 
PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.google.android.gms", 0); 
// Google Play services is installed 
} 
catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
{ 
// Google Play services is not installed 
}
```