# Is it possible to determine in my Java code what the store the app is installed from?

Tags: android

I have an Android app that displays some Ads. The app is published on Google Play and I am going to publish it on other stores like Huawei App Gallery, etc.. But ad provider requires to use different ad unit ids on different app stores.

Is it possible to determine in my Java code what the store the app is installed from?

Now in my Java code I simply set ad unit id with a code like this:

```
    iAd = new InterstitialAd(context);
    iAd.setAdUnitId(unit_id);
```

so I probably need to crate a map with app store as a key and unit id as a value and find my unit id by the app store the app is installed from.

Comment: [`PackageManager.getInstallSourceInfo()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#getInstallSourceInfo(java.lang.String)) should help. And before API 30 you could use [`PackageManager.getInstallerPackageName()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#getInstallerPackageName%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to get the installer source of android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70421457/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-installer-source-of-android-app)